# how to remove www from all urls of my website domain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove www from all urls of my website domain. I used following code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this code redirects only  `http://www.example.com` to  `http://example.com`
i want `http://www.example.com/abcd` as  `http://example.com/abcd` also

Please help me. your help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser.

Comment: Thanks for reply but my problem is not resolved..i want `http://www.example.com/abcd as http://example.com/abcd`

Comment: That's what this answer is doing. Make sure this rule is your first rule in root .htaccess and you test in a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```